# Convert columns to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to convert SQL data from row to column

This is my data

```
-------------------------------
|ITEM |    DAY  |  No  | Qty  |
-------------------------------
|  A  |Monday   | No 1 | 10   |
|  A  |Tuesday  | No 1 | 10   |
|  A  |Tuesday  | No 2 | 5    |
|  A  |Wednesday| NULL | NULL |
-------------------------------
```

I want to convert into one rows only and get this result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ITEM | Monday1|  Monday2 | Tuesday1 | Tuesday2 | Wednesday1 | Wednesday 2|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  A  |   10   |  NULL    |  10      |     5    |   NULL     |   NULL     |
```

How I can build the result?
I tried using a pivot table but still didn't get the result

Thank you

Comment: Also, the sample data doesn't align with the expected results. There's only a single Monday and Wednesday value in the sample data, yet there are multiple Monday/Wednesday columns, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pivot them

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ITEM
  , CONCAT([DAY], RIGHT([No],1)) AS Col
  , Qty
  FROM YourTable
) Src
PIVOT (
  MAX(Qty) 
  FOR Col IN (
    [Monday1], [Monday2], 
    [Tuesday1], [Tuesday2],
    [Wednesday1], [Wednesday2]
  ) 
) Pvt
ORDER BY ITEM;
```